# javascript algorithm for basic algebra?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, algebra

Does anybody know of an algorithm that can be applied to javascript to solve basic algebra?
For example:

> x + 5 = 11

Then return x, which would be 6.

Comment: A web search for _algebra symbolic solver javascript_ turns up lots of resources.

Comment: @Dineshkani how will eval solve that?

Comment: we can store the expression into string and index contain '=' will be the middle part for operation. ,if x happen to be before '=' . we change all signs (+ to -, * to / .. etc) of integers and can evaluate them with integers after '='. similar case for if x happen to be after '=' .

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing now, but it's harder than it seemed. I wrote down the steps for solving it on a piece of paper, coded it, then worked it out with the example problem i used (x + 5 = 11) and it works correctly, but not (5 + x = 11) or (x + 5 + 3 = 11)